# Does a bounty prevent a question from being closed as a duplicate?

Tags: support

I'm not sure if there is either a system restriction or (more likely) an informal code to not aggressively close questions that have a bounty on them. Whatever the reason, is it possible to close a question that has a bounty on it - and also, what happens if said question is merged into its duplicate (which also could use a more detailed answer), does the bounty 'jump across' to the new/old question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions with bounties cannot be closed at all, as described in [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100195/do-questions-with-bounty-have-more-resistance-to-closing). That way, we don't need any special rules regarding bounties and duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, didn't think to search on MSO for the answer.

Comment: In general, if what you are looking for is not particular to the site's topic, it's probably a general rule and will probably be found on MSO.